# What can I do for failover of lost TCP connection during running a program?

Tags: linux, tcp

I program distributed program in C++ that uses TCP and run it on linux cent os 7 with kernel 3.1.0

The program is built for high performance with high CPU, disk and network usage.

The program might run over a few days like 4 days. I am worried about the case where TCP connection is lost during the computation for any reason except for the case that one of machines died.

Can this happen? (The tcp connection is lost while the machines are all alive and no one invoked close on the socket?)

If possible, what can the programmer like me do for it?
Can I detect the lost connection and try to reconnect it?

Thanks,

Comment: You detect lost connections when `read` or `write` returns with an error. Then you close the connection and try to reconnect.

Comment: Anything can happen, of course. Any socket connection can experience network connectivity issues, for various reasons, at any given time.

Comment: To clarify - "failover" normally refers to e.g. connecting to a redundant server if the current connection fails - is that what you mean here?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth that's certainly not!. I will update my question

Comment: Not only your TCP connection but also your process can get lost. Linux kills processes randomly, if it is out of memory. A simple fork bomb accident in the shell can cause this, if the system is not configured properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, connection management is part of the protocol.  This way the management is documented and client and server know what is expected.

Some strategies:

- use UDP: no connection.  Handle request/reply and possible failures.  Timeout handling of reply may be needed.
- short TCP connections: only connect when needed and disconnect after "transaction" (e.g. http)
- long TCP connection with keep-alive checks and connection retries: check for connection failures and have client reconnect and servers wait for reconnection.

Comment: For the long TCP connection, what's the mechanism for connection retries? How can both the server and client be sure that they need to reconnect? Is there a typical pattern for it or or any reference..?

Comment: Using TCP_KEEPALIVE, at least each side knows when its connection is lost. Handling error condtions from send/receive seems like the best way to start the reconnection as already commented by Some programmer dude.